# Не могу сделать запрос к postgresql БД через Sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Работает просмотр созданных таблиц и создание новых. Таблица "ActiveTournaments" есть в списке таблиц.

```
class Database:

   def __init__(self):
       self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://')
       self.engine.connect()

   def create_table(self):
       metadata = MetaData()
       Table("ActiveTournaments", metadata,
                          Column("ID", Integer),
                          Column("chatID", Integer),
                          Column("ActiveNow", Integer),
                          Column("Status", String),
                          Column("ActiveAll", Integer),
                          Column("Name", String),
                          Column("MembersID", String),
                          )


        metadata.create_all(self.engine)

   def view_columns(self):
       session = Session(bind=self.engine)
       print(session.query('ActiveTournaments').all())


Database().view_columns()
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло такое решение

```
def view_column_names(self):                                                                                                                                                                      
    with self.engine.connect() as connection:                                                                                                                                                     
       result = connection.execute(text("select column_name from 
       information_schema.columns where table_name = 'ActiveTournaments'"))                                                            
       print(result.all())
```